# Append src in an image class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel

This is my code:

```
<img class="img-status">
```

```js
$('.img-status').append('src="{!! asset('pmc_assets/img/online.png') !!}"');
```

However, it gives me an error in the console:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'pmc_assets'. Expected ')' to end an argument list.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: you can't use PHP in JS/jQuery - they're seprate languages with their own syntax ... just use absolute url's if you're doing via jquery?

Comment: I've also just noticed you don't escape the single quotes inside the asset bracket, so it stops the append there.. that's also probably why it's not working :) you can use `\` to escape like: `string = 'my string doesn\'t even recognise the slasah'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the JS is written in the `blade` file, you could assign the result of asset to a variable and use that variable to alter the `src` of element

```
<script>

var source = "{!! asset('pmc_assets/img/online.png') !!}";

$('.img-status').attr('src', source);

</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

If it is in a separate JS File, one thing you could do is create an `hidden` input field in your blade file and access the value of it in JavaScript

**demo.blade.php**

```
<input type="hidden" name="image-source" 
       value="{{ asset('pmc_assets/img/online.png') }}" 
       id="image-source" />
```

**demo.js**

```
<script>

var source = $("#image-source").val();

$('.img-status').attr('src', source);

</script>
```

Comment: Actually it is written in a separate js file. Any idea? Because it just passes the string and not getting url.

Comment: @Rob check the updated answer, hope that answers your query